# Why doesn't this while loop break when iterating through pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, while-loop

When I run the code it seems to iterate through the whole dataframe twice and it ignores the while condition

```py
import pandas as pd

a = 0

sales = [
         {'account': 'Jones LLC', 'Jan': 150, 'Feb': 200, 'Mar': 140},
         {'account': 'Alpha Co',  'Jan': 200, 'Feb': 210, 'Mar': 215},
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 },
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 },
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 },
         {'account': 'Blue Inc',  'Jan': 50,  'Feb': 90,  'Mar': 95 }
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(sales)

while a <= 6:
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        df.loc[index, 'a'] = a
        print(a, index)
        a += 1

df
```

Comment: `iterrows` is very slow, can you explain what are you trying to do in the original requirement?

Comment: What is your desired output? Or are you just exploring the use of loops with `loc`? Because you can use methods that avoids using loops since loops takes a while to finish.

Comment: I have a dataframe of URL's and I am trying to append the server code as a column. I was hoping to keep it in a dataframe because this is running inside an Alteryx workflow. I was trying to trouble shoot and just limit the iterations, but it seems like the while statement is ignored.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess what you want is, that the assignemt stops after the 6th row, right?

That would be

```
a= 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'a'] = a
    print(a, index)
    a += 1
    if a == 6:
        break
```

The `while` loop indeed has an effect in your case. The loop body is executed twice, which explains the values 6...11 in column a. In the first iteration of the `while` loop a is zero, so it enteres the loop. As the inner loop has no restriction, it just loops over all records, increasing `a` in each iteration. If you have exactly 6 records in your df, it exits with `a==6` which means, that the `while` loop is iterated once more. Then finally `a == 12` and it terminates leaving your dataframe with values 6 ... 11 in column a, which are the values set by the second iteration of the while loop.

Comment: Got it. I didn't realize that the inner loop would run without considering the conditions of the parent loop. Seems like a basic concept I am missing

Comment: No, it's actually 6. Note, the first execution of the loop body of the `for ... iterrows()` starts with `a==0` and ends with `a==1`-

Comment: Correct. It's not like a constraint or something. The while condition is only evaluated whenever it has to be checked if another iteration is required. So if the end of the loop body is reached or if a `continue` statement is executed which belongs to the same loop.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
a=0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df.loc[index, 'a'] = a
    print(a, index)
    a += 1
```

While loop is not necessary, because for stop when there aren't more dict in the list. If you would want use while loop you should use <6 instead , not <=6 because when for finally a=6 and then the for loop would run again.

Comment: Yeah I should have used < 6 or some other number. That explains why it was running twice. What I really wanted it to do was just break early without iterating through the whole dataframe